# nServiceBus UnicastBusConfig.MessageEndpointMappings.Endpoint

Tags: c#, service, nservicebus, bus

I am playing with custom config for NServiceBus and I am implementing IConfigurationSource.

In the case of UnicastBusConfig, what is property UnicastBusConfig.MessageEndpointMappings[n].Endpoint supposed to be?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Endpoint property is the address of the target endpoint, usually in the format `"queue@machine"` or `"queue"` when it is on a local machine.

Answer (score 0):

It is a name of your QUEUE.

```
<UnicastBusConfig>
   <MessageEndpointMappings>
     <add Messages="YOURASSEMBLYNAME" Endpoint="NAMEOFQUEUE@MACHINENAME"></add>
   </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
```